# Item not deleting from quote in Magento2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, quote, quoteitem

I have used observer to delete the quote item.

Used this event **controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index**

This is the code of my **etc/events.xml**.

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index">
    <observer name="change_quote_item_price" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\DeleteItem" />
</event>
```

Then **Vendor\Module\Observer\DeleteItem.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface; 
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http as ResponseHttp;

class DeleteItem implements ObserverInterface{
  private $logger;
  protected $_messageManager;
  protected $_resource;
  protected $checkoutSession;
  protected $redirect;
  protected $cart;
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
  ){
    this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;  
    $this->redirect = $redirect;
   $this->cart = $cart; 
 }
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer){

    try{
      $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
            $quoteItems = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
            $isExist= false;
            foreach($quoteItems as $item) {
                    $productSku = $item->getSku();
                    $itemId = $item->getItemId();

                    $checkTable  = $this->checkProduct($productSku);
                    if($checkTable ){
                        $isExist= true;
                        $this->cart->removeItem($itemId)->save();                           
                        continue;
                    } 
                    $item->setQty(1);
                    $item->save();
            }
            $quote->collectTotals();

            $message = "You can't buy this product!!";
            if($isExist){
                $this->_messageManager->addError(__($message));             
                $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
                $this->redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), 'checkout');
            }

    }catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->info(' --CheckoutBeforeException--  '.$e->getMessage());
    }
  }

 public function checkProduct($productSku){
   $connection = $this->getConnection();
   $sql = "select * from custom_table where sku='".$productSku."'";
   $resultProduct = $connection->query($sql);
   $resultQuery = $resultProduct->fetchAll();

   if(!empty($resultQuery)){ 
     $parent_sku = $resultQuery[0]['parent_sku'];
     return true;
   }
  }else{
    return false;
   }
  }

 public function getConnection(){
    $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
    return $connection;

  }

 }
```

This is not deleting the item, actually my observer file is firing. Item not deleting completely.

If navigated to cart page it is showing as summary with subtotal 0. Then in minicart also with qty 1.

Is any other code i need to use to delete the product from quote from itemId? Please anybody look into it and update me your answers. Thanks!!

Comment: Did you created sections.xml file?

Comment: @RohanHapani, No I am using even and observer, how to create section file, can u pls update me, I have used above code

Comment: @RohanHapani, Can you pls update your answer what change i need to make..

Comment: When do you want the item to be deleted from quote?

Comment: @aravind, if checkProduct function return value is true..

Comment: $this->cart property doesn't have any class injected in constructor?

Comment: @aravind, it is there, i forgot to mention, I'll update now

Comment: Have you tried my solution of using quote?

Answer (score 1):

Inject **Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface** class in constructor

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository) 
{
    $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
}
```

**now use bellow code to delete item from quote**

```
$quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive(QUOTE_ID);

foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item)
{
    $quote->deleteItem($item)->save();
}

$this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
```

Comment: do i need to use this line?$quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive(QUOTE_ID);
because already i am loading quote items

Comment: okay then no need i just give you reference

Comment: Still same issue, its not clearing the item completely.. i can see empty summary with total 0

Answer (score 0):

Actually this deletes the product from cart,as well as from tables in **quote_item**, **quote_item_option**. I have just now tested using custom controller

```
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
```

create property

```
$this->checkoutSession   = $checkoutSession;
$this->cart              = $cart;
```

call quote function for removing item by item id

```
 $allItems =  $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
 foreach ($allItems as $item) {
       $cartItemId = $item->getItemId();
       $this->cart->removeItem($cartItemId)->save();
 }
```

Comment: hi @aravind, I am trying it now.

Comment: hi @aravind, same issue after that also..

Comment: Do i need to use save() method after that line?

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: hi @aravind, No the one u given is not worked for me

Comment: @ravind,do i need to use save() method after that line?

Comment: i think you need to find a method where we should load quote item id and use delete() like $quoteid = $this->_quote->load($quoteItemid);$quoteid->delete()

Comment: can u please update as answer.. @aravind

Comment: i have updated the answer, check whether you are using exact same code

Comment: yes I am using exactly like ur code, you can check in my question, there is no change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96335/discussion-between-aravind-and-manjunath).